# Is it possible to @-reference via Facebooks api?

Tags: facebook

Using Facebooks web api you can refer to user, pages and other objects in your messages by typing the @-sign and then search/select. I wonder if it is possible to place such links in messages using any of Facebook API:s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to @-mention without using Facebook UI. There were loopholes at one point, but these no longer exist.

Comment: Hi phwd. Do you know why Facebook removed this hability from their API? This was possible in earlier versions of the PHP SDK.

Comment: @jesusbet because it annoyed users who were tagged; most likely because developers were abusing it.